# microsoft wedge mobile keyboard

Tags: mobile, keyboard, wedge

I have a "Microsoft wedge mobile keyboard".  It changes the Function key to play, mute, search, share, etc...  I cannot find any driver or programs for this keyboard.
Can I change it back to normal function key instead?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.autohotkey.com/

With this script, work for me!

```
Media_Play_Pause::F1
Volume_Mute::F2
Volume_Down::F3
Volume_Up::F4
<+#F21::F5
<!<#F21::F6
<^<#F21::F7
<#F21::F8
PrintScreen::F9
Home::F10
End::F11
PgUp::F12
F1::Media_Play_Pause
F2::Volume_Mute
F3::Volume_Down
F4::Volume_Up
F5::<+#F21
F6::<!<#F21
F7::<^<#F21
F8::<#F21
F9::PrintScreen
F10::Home
F11::End
F12::PgUp
```

Answer (score 1):

Reply from MVP, they said it is hardware function, which means it cannot be changed.  It is not for a programmer to use it.  :(